# GLib docs say that g_file_has_key() is deprecated because it uses GError, but where is the new, replacement function?

Tags: updates, deprecated, glib

GLib [docs](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Error-Reporting.html#gerror-rules) say that [g_key_file_has_key()](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Key-value-file-parser.html#g-key-file-has-key) is deprecated because it uses `GError`, but where is the new, replacement function? I cannot spot any reasonable candidate for it… From the documentation, it should use a `gboolean *` `error_out` parameter instead of the `GError **error_out` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`g_key_file_has_key()` is not deprecated, and the documentation does not say it is. It does say that the function doesn’t follow all of the `GError` conventions, but that does not mean it’s deprecated.

It means that to use the function properly you must do:

```
g_autoptr(GError) local_error = NULL;
gboolean has_key = g_key_file_has_key (kf, group, key, &local_error);
if (local_error != NULL)
  /* handle error */
```

rather than doing:

```
g_autoptr(GError) local_error = NULL;
if (!g_key_file_has_key (kf, group, key, &local_error))
  /* handle error */
```

Comment: The html page under the «docs» link says: "*There are functions in GLib itself such as g_key_file_has_key() that are deprecated because of this.*", which is a clear statement about the function deprecation… Is the (a somewhat side) documentation wrong?

Comment: The `GError` documentation shouldn’t say that; I’ll fix it soon. Thanks for pointing it out.

If a function is deprecated, the documentation for that function will say so; that’s the canonical way of marking a deprecation.

Comment: Fix available here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/merge_requests/1838

Comment: Thanks for the fix :)